# Text extraction using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, tags

I have html data like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <script type="text/blzscript">
    </script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <p class="status-box">In some countries, this medicine may only be approved for veterinary use.</p>
    <h3>Scheme</h3>
    <p>Rec.INN</p>
    <h3>CAS registry number (Chemical Abstracts Service)</h3>
    <p>0000850-52-2</p>
    <h3>Chemical Formula</h3>
    <p>C21-H26-O2</p>
    <h3>Molecular Weight</h3>
    <p>310</p>
    <h3>Therapeutic Category</h3>
    <p>Progestin</p>
    <h3>Chemical Names</h3>
    <p>17α-Allyl-17-hydroxyesta-4,9,11-trien-3-one (WHO)</p>
    <p>Estra-4,9,11-trien-3-one, 17β-hydroxy-17-(2-propenyl)- (USAN)</p>
    <h3>Foreign Names</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>Altrenogestum (Latin)</li>
        <li>Altrenogest (German)</li>
        <li>
            <a href="altr%C3%A9nogest.html">Altrénogest</a> (French)
        </li>
        <li>Altrenogest (Spanish)</li>
    </ul>
    <h3>Generic Names</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>Altrenogest (OS: BAN, USAN)</li>
        <li>
            <a href="altr%C3%A9nogest.html">Altrénogest</a> (OS: DCF)
        </li>
        <li>A 35957 (IS)</li>
        <li>A 41300 (IS)</li>
        <li>RH 2267 (IS)</li>
        <li>RU 2267 (IS: RousselUclaf)</li>
    </ul>
    <h3>Brand Names</h3>
    <div class='contentAdRight' id='third_ad_unit'>
        <div class='adsense-ad adsense-ad-text-image-flash-html adsense-ad-300 adsense-ad-300x600 adsense-ad-international'>
            <script type="text/blzscript">
            google_ad_client="pub-3964816748264478";google_ad_channel="";google_ad_format="300x600_pas_abgc";google_ad_width="300";google_ad_height="600";google_ad_type="text,image,flash,html";google_color_border="FFFFFF";google_color_bg="FFFFFF";google_color_link="0000FF";google_color_text="000000";google_color_url="008000";google_analytics_domain_name="drugs.com";
            </script>
            <h1></h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and i want to extract :

Foreign names , generic names and brand names: 
I tried

```
test = soup.select('h1')[0].text.strip()
print(test)
```

But it is not giving what i want i also tried to extract for script but none of them are giving result as i required

Comment: you are behind `drugs.com` for a while. This is your [url](https://www.drugs.com/international/altrenogest.html)

Comment: Your `h1 ` is empty see: `<h1></h1>` in your html.

Comment: Learn about 'html' before scrapping.

Comment: That is h3, and thanks for suggestion.

Comment: what python and bs version do you use?

Comment: python3 and bs4,

Comment: i am trying:   import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

proxies = {"https":"https://******:*****************@proxy.home.com:8080"}
newURL='https://www.drugs.com/international/atipamezole.html'        
#print("newURL",newURL)
#newURL1=newURL.replace(" ","")
sr=''
page1 = requests.get(newURL,proxies=proxies)
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(page1.content, 'html.parser')

for div in soup1.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'contentBox'}):
    DrugSynoNames = div.find('ul')
    sr=DrugSynoNames.get_text()
    
print(sr)